# Why "de-IT" is a valid CultureInfo on local but not on production?

Tags: c#, localization, cultureinfo, culture, regional-settings

I'm validating a new culture, the country part comes from a user-selection and needs to be checked, so i'm using this code:

```
string language = submittedCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;  // de
string countryCode = GetIso3166Country(model.Country); // submitted Italy and countryCode IT
string cultureString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryCode)
    ? language
    : $"{language}-{countryCode}";
bool validCulture = cultureString.TryParseCultureInfo(out CultureInfo newCulture);
```

The `TryParseCultureInfo` is a simple extension method using [`CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultureinfo?view=net-5.0#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_GetCultureInfo_System_String_):

```
public static bool TryParseCultureInfo(this string stringValue, out CultureInfo value)
{
    value = null;
    if (stringValue == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        value = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(stringValue);
        return true;
    }
    catch (CultureNotFoundException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If i test it locallly everything works as expected. I get a culture for `"de-IT"`, so validation succeeds and i will resolve the redirect-url as next step. But on production(actually UAT) it fails, the culture is not supported.

Does every culture need to be installed? If i try "it-IT" it works also on production, so it seems that not italy is the problem but that "de-IT" does not exist. Why is the behavior so different, what causes it and what can i do to get the same behavior locally and on production?

Would it be an option to use [`CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to create that culture on app-start or what is the best solution? **Edit**: I tried that but you need administrative rights which is not possible.

So what would be the best way to circumvent this issue even if that culture is not (yet) supported?

Comment: According to [LCID reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c) `de-IT` supported starting from release 10.2, which means Windows 10 v1703. Please, check OS version on production, since supported language tag depends on Windows version

Comment: @Pavel This is what I was wondering.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: thanks, interesting. I think we use server 2016 on production which would be release 10.1. Anyway, i'm still wondering what would be the best way to circumvent this issue even if that culture is not (yet) supported. Because i just want to validate if it's potentially a valid cutlure, so i can use the string for my redirect-url. It's not necessary that i can actually use that culture. If you have an idea make your comment an answer

Comment: @TimSchmelter not sure, that it's an answer, I put only a documentation reference:) If `de-IT` isn't supported, you can use `de` culture as fallback for example (it's supported from Windows 7)