# RegionInfo by country code returns different EnglishName

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, regioninfo

I have a unit with this line of code

```
var countryName = new RegionInfo("KR").EnglishName;
```

if I run it on local machine the EnglishName is "Korea", but if this test is running in github, EnglishName is "South Korea" and test fails.

I tried to play around with setting another CurrentCulture for the Thread, but nothing changed.

Any suggestions how to get same result on different envs?

Comment: Different environments are different, maybe you have a different OS. I had a similar question where the result was different because of a different windows version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902267/why-de-it-is-a-valid-cultureinfo-on-local-but-not-on-production Why do you need to ensure that the `EnglishName` of the "KR"-culture is "Korea" and not "South Korea"?

Comment: thanks, that was the reason - on github tests were running under ubuntu.

Comment: in this test I'm maing sure I collected correct address line